# Should properties be emitted as methods using Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, reflection.emit

I'm using types from the `Reflection.Emit` namespace for generating a dynamic assembly on the fly (with dynamic types in it).

Both Reflection and the `Reflection.Emit` namespace provide APIs for dealing with methods and properties of CLR types.

To my knowledge, properties are implemented as methods by the C# compiler, and so i'm wondering how should these be treated when emitting them dynamically?

Should Properties be emitted by using a `MethodBuilder` or using a `PropertyBuilder`? (i.e: by calling `DefineMethod` or `DefineProperty` ?)

Is there any recommendation for one approach over the other?

Comment: Using PropertyBuilder.SetSetMethod and SetGetMethod() is certainly advisable.  And yes, they take a MethodBuilder.

Comment: @HansPassant, surely that is an answer?  *bows to your infinite wisdom* :)

Comment: There must be more to this question, I don't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should properties be emitted by using a `MethodBuilder` or using a `PropertyBuilder`?

Both. If you have a read-write property `X`, then in CIL it's represented as a a get method (usually called `get_X`), a set method (usually called `set_X`) and a properly called `X` that points to the two methods.

So, to create a property using Reflection.Emit, you should:

1. Use `MethodBuilder` to create the get method (probably reading from some field).
2. Use another `MethodBuilder` to create the set method (probably writing to the same field).
3. Use `PropertyBuilder` to create the property, setting its `Name` and calling `SetGetMethod()` and `SetSetMethod()`.

If you want to create a read-only property, just skip step 2 and don't call `GetSetMethod()`.

Comment: So at the CIL is there or is there not a concept of a Property? according to the answer, there are 2 methods with a "property" that holds them together.

Comment: @lysergic-acid That's exactly what it is: a method for each accessor and also a property that links the methods. You might want to have a look at [§II.17 of the CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#222) (if you do, you can ignore the `.other` part, AFAIK, it's not used in C#).